# Creating a record with values passed by query string

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, hidden

I am creating a record in a table that has foriegn key in it. The foriegn key is getting passed in the query string and I have set the value in the ViewBag. I have added this to the form but it will not work.
Here is the code from the controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(int propertyId)
{
        ViewBag.storagePropertyId = propertyId;
        return View();
}
```

Here is the code from the view.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.propertyId, new { value =ViewBag.propertyId })
```

Is this how I should be doing this? If so, is there a problem with that form

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the value of the `Model.PropertyID` in the controller, or better yet in a viewmodel.

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel()
{
   public int PropertyID { get; set; }

   public MyViewModel() { } 

   public MyViewModel(int propertyID)
   {
      this.PropertyID = propertyID;
   }
}
```

**Action Result**

```
public ActionResult Create(int propertyId)
{
   return View(new MyViewModel(propertyId));
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PropertyID)
```

Then the value of the Hidden field will contain the value of the property ID.

Comment: Ok, so lets just say the model currently has ExpenseID, PropertyID (this is the foreign key), Field1, etc. When I create the viewModel, how will it know to add the viewModel values to the expenses table?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The expense record I am creating has to be related to a property, it is required to have a propertyId. So from the property detail page I have a button for adding an expense record. I just need to be able to get the correct property id into the expense record I am creating. I understand this is a VERY basic task and I appreciate your time. -John

Comment: What are you using for your database? Are you using an orm?

Comment: sql server express. I am using the mvc EF with database first. I am just trying to get this done using the ef created view for creating the expense.